# Single View Sign Up or Multi-View Sign Up?

Tags: mobile, ios, signup-signon

Is there any research on whether users prefer a single sign up view over a multi-view sign up process?

What is your take on this?

[image]

Comment: Users prefer it all in one place. [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/) thinkers are moving toward multi-view. It's one of those places where the micro-experience may have to give a little for the sake of larger security concerns. Ultimately, the experience of an app that gets hacked is terrible.

Answer (score 3):

Use social login :-)

Jokes aside, it takes the same number of steps to between three input boxes on one screen versus three input boxes on three screens.

However, it's always nice if you can set an expectation for the user by showing how many and what pieces of info they need to fill.

Answer (score 2):

Pros of multi-view:

- You can verify that each field is valid before letting the user proceed to the next field.
- You can press enter to go to the next field instead of tab which is nice because many users often press enter without thinking since that is what you need to press after filling out the last field.

Pros of single view:

- For users, single view will appear as simpler. Simple always wins!
- When users see a form with let's say 5 steps, they will automatically calculate that the form will take 5 times as long to fill out as a form with only one step. They have no way of knowing that each step is only one short field.
- Multi-view sign in will seem more complicated to a user since it is an entire extra step.
- By showing everything on one screen, users right away see everything they will need to fill out. Users like to be in the know :)
- It is easier for users to correct previous field when they can just click on an above field, instead of needing to go back a whole page.
- Many users will be using touch devices. On these devices, many users prefer just tapping on the next field instead of using tab or enter.

Answer (score 1):

Single View ftw! Since typing your username and password is so standard, most people look at the keyboard most of the time and hit enter automatically. In the single view you could instantly see any typos as a user in a multiview you would have to go back between screens. Plus the single view is the regular, that users are used to - don't reinvent the wheel.